# Should I sign assemblies used in asp.net MVC / WebAPI app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, code-signing, assembly-signing

When searching for answers about assembly signing, I'm finding results around the year 2010. And I'm thinking those answers relate more to Desktop development than to Web dev.

Nowadays, if I'm writing my own web app, that I'll publish on my own Azure account, should I sign my assemblies? I don't think about deploying it publicly and letting other people use this assembly. It is only used on my own solution.

[image: Assembly signing]

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses some other projects that are signed because of legacy desktop software. My real question is: Can I remove the signing part from it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of code signing is to confirm who the author of the software is, and also to confirm that it has not been tampered with (altered or corrupted) since it was signed.

When you publish a web app to a server you're in control of, there's no advantage to code signing. You know where your own code came from, and as long as your server is secured properly, you know that it won't be tampered with.

Nobody else has access to your assemblies apart from you, so when you're creating a web app, there's no need to worry about code signing.